# macOS Catalina (10.15) not using correct Python interpreter within virtual environment

Tags: mac, python, virtualenv

Since updating to Catalina, after activating a virtual environment, it does not affect which python interpreter is called when using the python or python3 command. I confirmed that I am still using Bash as default in my terminal.

I use the `which python` command and it shows that it is using the system version of python.

**django_env**:

```
MacB:django_blog user$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

**django_env**:

```
MacB:django_blog user$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

I am able to use the venv Python interpreter by referencing it by the absolute path, as a work around I was just going to setup aliases for each venv but was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue or better yet, someone had a fix for this.

Comment: Can you edit your Question to show exactly what command(s) you ran to create your venv?

Answer (score 1):

Existing venvs typically need to be re-created after the Python has been updated.  Any venvs created with a `python -m venv` command can be upgraded with the `--upgrade` option.